# Dynamically creating an iFrame with data from Observable in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe, https, youtube

I want to embed a number of youtube videos in my angular application via iframe.
The video-urls are stored in a database, in order to get the 3 most recent ones on each visit. 
 The "youtube"-component makes a call to a service and attempts to store the returned data in an Array like so:

youtube.comoponent.ts

```
youtubeData: Array<YoutubeData>
 
this.dataHubService.getYoutubeData().subscribe(data => this.youtubeData = data);
```

The "YoutubeData" interface looks like this:

```
export interface YoutubeData {
  videoUrl: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  userName: string;
}
```

and an Observable of the type Array is returned by the http call in the service like so:

```
 getYoutubeData(): Observable<Array<YoutubeData>>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Array<YoutubeData>>('http://localhost:80/getYTdata.php');
  }
```

The youtube.component then attempts to loop over the youtubeData-Array in the template using *ngFor, giving the contents of each items as inputs to a youtube-video.component:

youtube.component.html

```
<app-youtube-video *ngFor="let video of youtubeData;" [title]="video.title" [description]="video.description" [username]="video.userName" [videoId]="video.videoUrl">
</app-youtube-video>
```

youtube-video.component.html (simplified)

```
<div>{{username}} presents: {{title}}</div>
<iframe [src]=videoUrl></iframe>
<div>{{description}}</div>
```

So that's the situation, and whoever worked with iFrame before might have already seen where this is going:
The iFrame refuses to use an unsafe url as its source. In order to signal that it's a trusted url, it would need to go through something like `this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(videoUrl)` but a method call like that doesn't seem to work even inside the subscribe() method.
How do I turn the url into a SafeResourceUrl in an async context like an Observable?
Is there a way to save a specific state of the data returned by the Observable for outside-access? I've tried things like `.pipe(tap(data => this.youtubeData = data)).subscribe()` but to no effect, the url was always undefined when accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

Add optional safeUrl field in interface

```
export interface YoutubeData {
  videoUrl: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  userName: string;
  safeUrl?: string;
}
```

generate safeUrl in observable like below

```
this.dataHubService.getYoutubeData().subscribe(data => {
    this.youtubeData = data;
    this.youtubeData.forEach(d => {
        d.safeUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(d.videoUrl);
    });
});
```

Use safeUrl instead of videoUrl

```
<app-youtube-video *ngFor="let video of youtubeData;" [title]="video.title" [description]="video.description" [username]="video.userName" [videoId]="video.safeUrl">
</app-youtube-video>


<div>{{username}} presents: {{title}}</div>
<iframe [src]=safeUrl></iframe>
<div>{{description}}</div>
```

See if this works

Comment: Didn't seem to help, sadly. I also logged the values of both d.url and d.safeUrl within the forEach() method:
"URL within foreach:undefined"
"safeURL after assign: SafeValue must use [property]=binding: undefined (see https://g.co/ng/security#xss)"